# What does glutTimerFunc() actually do?

Tags: opengl, glut

If I run the following loop as part of my OpenGL program:

```
void Loop(int state)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(1, Loop, 0);
}
```

Then, my program runs fine, and I am able to move the camera around the scene by dragging my mouse.

However, if I use this loop:

```
void Loop(int state)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    Loop();
}
```

I am not able to move around the scene with my mouse. The loop is being called, but it is just not processing any mouse or keyboard inputs.

I don't understand why this is. The only difference is that in the first example, a timer function is used to call `Loop()`, whereas in the second example, `Loop()` is called explicitly, without any delay.

So what is it that `glutTimerFunc()` is actually doing, besides calling `Loop()`?

Comment: You can always look it up in the sources https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/git_master/freeglut/freeglut/src/fg_callbacks.c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example, `glutTimerFunc` ensures `Loop` is called after 1 millisecond, however it returns and *does not wait*, meaning `Loop` in this case returns almost immediately.

In the second example, `Loop` is calling itself which results in infinite recursion and locks up your program's main thread, which would explain why nothing works in that case. `Loop`, then, never returns. If you left your program running long enough, your system would run out of memory due to the infinite recursion.

Comment: Actually the way Loop calls itself at the end of itself can be done by "tail recursion" which is possible without creating a new stack frame and thus gives and infinite loop without ever hitting a stack overflow.